# Keep query string for external urls

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

A user can be sent to the main website by some referral id, using a query string:

```
www.site.com/?ref=XXX
```

And when they click on a link to a login area, this query string must go with that external link:

```
https://internal.site.com?ref=XXX
```

I am working with wordpress, so I cannot append `?ref=<?php echo $_GET['ref']?>` to that link.

I have already changed `.htaccess` to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Every link back to the main website keeps the query strings, but external urls do not.

```
www.site.com?ref=XXX [original]
www.site.com/go/reds?ref=XXX [query strings are kept]
https://internal.site.com [query strings are removed]
```

The `QSA` flag in `htaccess` should do the trick, but it's not working for external links.

Comment: These RewriteRule, that you cited above, do not work with an external url in any kind at all. So it will be nice, to see those RewriteRule, in which you try to work with an external url. We need some context, to understand  root of problem.

Comment: @Eugeny hope it's clear now!

Comment: So on every external link, you want your referral link?

Comment: seems the following should resolve your problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/279996/how-do-you-redirect-urls-with-a-query-string-to-another-host

Comment: I edited your post for better understanding, just waiting for the edit to go through. If I understand correctly, you cannot append query strings to the links *in your code* at all, but whenever the user clicks on a link – whether it's an internal or external link – the original query string should be kept / appended?

Comment: @ErickEngelhardt, could you get back to us to clarify?

Comment: @ErickEngelhardt, I think the only way is using JS, I can get you a sample code if you want.

Comment: If the extrnal link is built with php you should put the query strings arguments with php, this is not related to apache. But be carefull,`<?php echo $_GET['ref']` is a huge security mistake, what if this arguments contains html or javascript code?

Comment: @Kiyan please, write it down.

Comment: @regilero but you can always striptags and filter content before echoing.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't edit the url since you are working with WordPress... I would think that would be easier than attempting to do .htaccess rewrites and all that.  Can you elaborate on why you can't modify WordPress' PHP code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding this script at the end of your page. This code will pass variables to every links on client side.

```
<p><a href="/about/">Internal</a></p>
<p><a href="https://google.com">External</a></p>
<p><a href="/post/?id=1">Link with query string</a></p>

<script>
    var index = window.location.href.indexOf('?')
    if(index != -1){
        var querystring = window.location.href.slice(index + 1)
        var tagA = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

        for(var i = 0; i < tagA.length; i++){
            var href = tagA[i].getAttribute('href');

            href += (href.indexOf('?') != -1)? '&' : '?';
            href += querystring;

            tagA[i].setAttribute('href', href);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This code is wrong. The href variable is a number so indexOf cannot be used on it.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the custom query everytime a the_permalink() function is called, you can use this filter

```
function append_query_string($url) {
    if (isset($_GET['ref'])) {
        $url = add_query_arg('ref', $_GET['ref']);
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter('the_permalink', 'append_query_string');
```

But it could be inconvenient option 'cause it is applied only to the link generated with the_permalink function, so you have to apply this function also to menus, post type archive link, and, in general, where you generate the link without the wp permalink function.

Another solution could be store the ref inside a session cookie or the $_SESSION global: in this case the reference will be lost everytime the user browser is clodes, so you can track the reference also if the user manually return to your site after been referred.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryString = "";
$x = 0;
foreach($_GET as $key=>$value){
    $queryString[$x]= "&$key=$value;
    $x++;
}
$url = $url."?".implode("&",$queryString);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and workable js function to accomplish this:

```
function addQueryParamsToLinks() {
  const links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  const queryParams = window.location.search;
  for (const link of links) {
    link.setAttribute("href", `${link.getAttribute("href")}${queryParams}`);
  }
}
```